# Fit png image middle of view

Tags: react-native

*I try to put my png image middle of  view. But it doesnt appear.*

*when I change somethings in code and image is appear but it comes so big. I couldnt fix this.*

```
<View style={{position: 'relative',alignItems:'center',flex:1}}>  
        <LinearGradient colors={['#DDDCDC', '#856F6F']} style= {{opacity: 0.6,flex:1}}>
        </LinearGradient>

        <View style={{position:'absolute', height:60,bottom:0}}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../image/datalog.png')} style={{height: '100%',width:'100%'}} >
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>

    </View>
```

Comment: Why are you using ImageBackground?

Comment: What should I use

Comment: ImageBackground is used for using Images as Background (as name suggests). If you just want to show a image in middle, use Image instead of ImageBackground.